# IBM DataStage : Datetime overflow

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I'm getting error which says `ODBC_Connector_14,0: ODBC function "SQLExecute" reported:  SQLSTATE = 22008: Native Error Code = 0: Msg = [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Datetime field overflow (CC_OdbcDBStatement::executeInsert, file CC_OdbcDBStatement.cpp, line 834)`. My input data type is Date in the source, i use select statement, the output of the source i set it the Date columns with length and scale = 0, in the database i set their length and scale to 0 too but somehow it does not eliminate the error and somehow not all records are input to the database. What is actually wrong? if it does needs length and the scale, i don't know how to determine it from the select statement, also i don't see any error messages about the date length/scale. It's just simply Datetime overflow. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a SELECT or an INSERT/UPDATE statement?

It's unusual to have a date overflow in a SELECT, because it's already a date in the database table.

On INSERT/UPDATE it is possible to provide a value that's too large for the database server to handle.  The largest possible date is different with different databases.

By the way, you don't need to provide a Length for the Date data type.  It will be ignored.